# What is the meaning of "I meet a tiger of escaping"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence?

> "I meet a tiger of escaping"

Does it mean "I meet a tiger, and I am escaping from a tiger"?
Does it mean "I meet a tiger, and the tiger is escaping from me"?

I have often met "Subect + verb + noun + "of + ~ing ".
Is "of escaping" a subject complement or a object complement?

Comment: It sounds like nonsense to this native speaker. (If there was no "of", it could make sense: _I meet a tiger escaping._) It might help if you shared some of the sentences that you have "often met" in this format.

Comment: Where did you find this? We're going to need more context--as it stands this  sentence doesn't mean anything obvious.

Comment: A few days ago I saw a sentence similar in structure and I captured the sentence to question, but I can not find the sentence in my folders. i may had not saved the sentence. I have been serching English grammar for several days to see if "of ~ing" of "S+V+ noun + of + ~ ing" can be used as a subject complement. But I could not find it. If I find exactly the example sentence, let me present it.

Comment: "He enter the room dancing" of "S+V+noun + ~ing" mean not "He enter the room and the room is dancing" but " he enter the room and he is dancing".  Can "he saw a dog dancing" of "S+V+noun + ~ing" mean not "he saw a dog and a dog is dancing" but " he saw a dog and he is dancing" ?  To reduce the confusion, I thought I could express "of ~ ing" as " a subject complement". ==> If so , "he saw a dog of dancing" ---> he saw a dog and he is dancing". My English grammar is all messed up.

Comment: Your "He saw a dog dancing" example is a better example; it's too bad you didn't use that in your question. Yes, the sentence is ambiguous: it could mean "He saw a dog and the dog was dancing," or "He saw a dog while he was dancing." Usually the context makes it clear which interpretation is the correct one.

Comment: i can't find that phrase anywhere on Google. If we can get context, perhaps this can be answered.

Comment: It sounds like somebody's playing an RPG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence you offer as an example is incorrect - it makes no sense with the word "of" in it.

If you remove "of" to form the sentence:

> I met a tiger escaping

it is **ambiguous**: you might be escaping or the tiger might be escaping.  It is also possible that both are escaping, though in that case, the sentence would probably draw attention to that coincidence.  It does not mean the tiger is escaping from you - since then you would not "meet" it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Google's definition of 'of':

[image]

All of these definitions are having to do with expressing some *one* thing as a relationship between two things.

*Of* does not work to express two separate things or two separate actions.  Nothing that uses the word *and* will be synonymous with "X of Y".